# Jwplayer : Error loading player: No playable sources found

Tags: php, wowza, jwplayer6

I am implementing video playing with jwplayer 6. 
I have premium edition account. also using wowza server for streaming.

```js
jwplayer.key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
jwplayer("player2").setup({
  width: 640,
  height: 360,
  file: "http://209.126.101.166:1935/redirect/hls/ktv33?scheme=m3u8",
  androidhls: true,
  provider: 'http',
  modes: [{
    type: 'flash',
    src: 'jwplayer.flash.swf'
  }],
  flashplayer: 'jwplayer.flash.swf',
  html5player: 'jwplayer.html5.js'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>

<div>
  <div style='clear:both;'>
    <br>
  </div>

  <h2>KTV in JW Player </h2>
  <div id='player2'></div>
</div>
```

Its getting an error : "Error loading player: No playable sources found"

Can you please help me out ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe [JWPlayer handles 302 redirects](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430189-about-hls-streaming) over hls of which the Wowza Load Balancer utilizes.  iOS client does handle it appropriately though (if you were looking to test this LB functionality).

Answer (score 1):

It is late but may be someone who having same issue later can use this.

You can add "type": "mp4" in your jwplayer setup() call if the file doesn't have file extension.

This solved this issue in my app where I am using JWPlayer 7

Hope it helps.

Comment: could you post an example how to add mp4  as type ?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the JW Player does not handle 302 redirects over hls.

Also, your code can be cleaned up a bit:

```
jwplayer.key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
jwplayer("player2").setup({
  width: 640,
  height: 360,
  file: "http://209.126.101.166:1935/redirect/hls/ktv33?scheme=m3u8",
  androidhls: true
});
```

However, it looks like  - http://209.126.101.166:1935/redirect/hls/ktv33?scheme=m3u8 is down, do you have a demo that is up?

Comment: Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 209.126.101.166:1935, please advise.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience. I replaced streaming link which is working now. You can check it. Please, suggest me solution. Check this demo page
http://tamiliptv.tv/jw/jw/jwplayer.html

Comment: http://68.235.42.75:1935/redirect/in2/kalaiudp.stream_720p/?scheme=m3u8 does not work. Go to it in a browser, it is just a white page.

Comment: If you are going to open in chrome,  its asking to save playlist.m3u8 to save, means its working. And if we are looking it in Firefox it's just a white page.

Comment: Definitely not working, sorry. I get this error in VLC - Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'http://68.235.42.75:1935/redirect/in2/kalaiudp.stream_720p/?scheme=m3u8'. Check the log for details.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue serving mp3 files. The solution for me was to modify my url from this:

`http://.../12345`

to this:

`http://.../12345.mp3`

The mime type was set correctly, so maybe there is are some filename checks in the jwplayer javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Before you try the technical answers above, double check that the JW Player account is active and billing is up to date. HLS streaming is a premium feature, even if you're not hosting the files on their servers.